# How do I in FloPy Modflow6 output MAW head values for all timesteps?

Tags: flopy

I am creating a MAW well and want to use it as an observation well to compare it later to field data, it should be screened over multiple layers. However, I am only getting the head value in the well of the very last timestep in my output file. Any ideas on how to get all timesteps in the output?

The FloPy manual says something about it needing to be in Output Control, but I can't figure out how to do that:

```
print_head (boolean) –   print_head (boolean) keyword to indicate that the list of multi-aquifer well heads will be printed to the listing file for every stress period in which “HEAD PRINT” is specified in Output Control. If there is no Output Control option and PRINT_HEAD is specified, then heads are printed for the last time step of each stress period.
```

In the MODFLOW6 manual I see that it is possible to make a continuous output:
[modflow6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyVz3.png)

My MAW definition looks like this:

```
maw = flopy.mf6.ModflowGwfmaw(gwf, 
                      nmawwells=1, 
                      packagedata=[0, Rwell, minbot, wellhead,'MEAN',OBS1welllayers], 
                      connectiondata=OBS1connectiondata, 
                      perioddata=[(0,'STATUS','ACTIVE')], 
                      flowing_wells=False, 
                      save_flows=True, 
                      mover=True, 
                      flow_correction=True, 
                      budget_filerecord='OBS1wellbudget', 
                      print_flows=True, 
                      print_head=True,
                      head_filerecord='OBS1wellhead',
                      )
```

My output control looks like this:

```
oc = flopy.mf6.ModflowGwfoc(gwf,
                        budget_filerecord=budget_file,
                        head_filerecord=head_file,
                        saverecord=[('HEAD', 'ALL'), ('BUDGET', 'ALL'), ],
                        )
```

Hope this is all clear and someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the MAW observations file... it's not done in the OC package.

You can find the scripts for the three MAW examples in the MF6 documentation here:
https://github.com/MODFLOW-USGS/modflow6-examples/tree/master/notebooks

It looks something like this:

```
obs_file = "{}.maw.obs".format(name)
csv_file = obs_file + ".csv"
obs_dict = {csv_file: [
                ("head", "head", (0,)),
                ("Q1", "maw", (0,), (0,)),
                ("Q2", "maw", (0,), (1,)),
                ("Q3", "maw", (0,), (2,)),
                ]}
maw.obs.initialize(filename=obs_file, digits=10, print_input=True, continuous=obs_dict)
```